How to deploy data source from DEV to UAT
Background: the data source from oracle is moved to hdfs through sqoop (with shell script), and hive table is created (with sql script) in dev environment.
My question is, how can I promote my data source from dev to uat?
I understand the progress needs to go through dev, uat, and prod environment, but I don't know how the progress works in detail.
The release guideline I am told is:

commit the code to the repository
run jenkins to get the build id
...

Back to the question, which is related to the release guideline in order:
1.0. I should commit the shell script (of sqoop) and sql script (of hive) to the repository?
2.0. For each script above, I should create a project. So, I will need to create and link multiple projects to be executed?
2.1. In the "code management" section from a project, I should write down the repository url?
2.2. In the "command" section from a project, I should write down the directory of the script and execute the script?
2.2.1. But how does the jenkins know where the uat server is? I guess I should run the JIL script (autosys) which includes the shell script? (because I can configure the uat server with the JIL script)
2.2.2. how about the sql script? Also run the JIL script instead? And in the JIL script, I need to connect the beeline client, and execute the sql script?
Please help and provide feedback by the points, or I can be confused. Thanks.
